# Can abuse break a genius?

Tags: teaching, abuse

This question is motivated by the movie [Whiplash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2582802/) which justifies the abusive behavior of a teacher by the future success of the student. The idea is that if a student fails to become fanatically driven to the degree that (s)he ignores/survives/enjoys teacher's abuse, then (s)he is no potential genius and his/her departure from the field is no loss to the field and Humanity.

Science is, of course, very different from music (which is the subject of the movie), e.g., they have very different [Lorenz curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve). I.e., a Ph.D. in Physics at the 50th percentile in his class can still have a decent professional life. In Music, he will probably drop out of the field (like the drummer who switched to medicine in the movie).

Still, I wonder what influence abusive professors (e.g., [Landau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Landau)) could have on science. We will never know, of course, of any potential Einsteins who left the field because they were mistreated by their thesis advisors, but we might be able to find circumstantial evidence.

Statistical evidence: are there any studies correlating students' success with teachers' personality at the **high** end of the spectrum? (I.e., *very* talented graduate students, *very* famous professors, success is measured in Nobel Prizes or something similar).

Anecdotal evidence: are there any examples of students leaving their advisors because of abuse and still achieving great success in science?

PS. Please note that the important point here is the *high* end of the spectrum (i.e., not elementary school, and not even college). The critical aspect of the question is that the teacher can claim that he is the *senior colleague* of the student, and that their common interest is *advancing the field* rather than *educating the student*.

Comment: Can you focus a bit what you are asking?  Your title is about damage from abuse, your first paragraph is about personality types, and your second paragraph is about success after dropping out of a program...

Comment: There is abundance of apprentice-"evil master" relationships. Though, it is hard to tell in which cases it helped, in which - it was success despite of he circumstances, and - in which cases would-be geniuses were broken. In any case, if it is a question in history, it is a question in history.

Comment: @jakebeal: my question is intentionally broad because I have no idea which aspect might bring an answer. Which version can you answer? If you have anything to say, please say it and I will modify my question to fit your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Because of the way our systems work, at the top end of the distribution in fame, you will find people who are not only very good, but who also strongly desire to be famous and are very skilled self-promoters.  The market is simply too large for people to rise to the very top without that being the case.  And that means [they are more likely to be abusers as well](http://thenarcissistinyourlife.com/the-rise-of-high-level-socialized-sociopaths/).

Sufficient abuse, academic or otherwise, can destroy any person.

Abuse can also help the abuser, by allowing them to effectively exploit other people... and that in turn might help those who survive (or who also learn to profit from the strategies of abuse), because they have a famous supervisor.

So: abuse can be profitable to the abusers and their chosen disciples, but it's a bad deal for the rest of the human beings they interact with and should be resisted at every turn.

Answer (score 4):

Abuse of the wrong kind, at the wrong time, can break anyone.

I spent grades 3-7 fighting a near-total writing block, literally unable to put more than a sentence or two on paper though I was reading far above my grade. Driven into it by one abusive teacher whom I had made the mistake of correcting; brought out of it by one exceptional special-ed teacher who was able to give me assignments designed to gradually pierce that defensive shell.

I don't think that's the question you were asking, though.

Answer (score 2):

Movies are *intentionally* fantasy.  You certainly should not interpret them as telling you the truth about much of anything.

"Genius" and "talent" are mostly movie fantasy.  The literary "chosen one" is not a real thing.

Anyone can experience a sudden mental illness.  "Broken" is the wrong word to describe that.  They are just sick, and they may get better.  Abuse might cause that illness, but it can also happen with no know cause.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by giving my opinion ( I do not think your question has one answer, correct or otherwise) from your last point.

You mention that statistical evidence suggests that talented students come from famous teachers, and it is these elites who get the Nobel prize. Yes, it is true. But it is not just because of the so-called 'genius' qualities. Nobel prize committee does not confer its prize by using some heavenly mechanism which shows them the best candidate. Winning a Nobel prize not only requires a lot of hard work but *more* importantly requires lobbying. Being able to find other top researchers in that area who can give letters supporting you. And that is where this game changes.

By working with a famous professor, you get a headstart in forming those connections. You get to work in those areas that those "top" researchers consider the most important. You get evaluated by the 'best', 'cited' by the best and you get to collaborate with the 'best'. I hope you get the underlying reason behind the statistics, which you refer to. Geniuses are created in the minds of the observers and commentators, not in the labs. Not every deserving researcher is celebrated. You need to be a salesman too, to be called a 'genius'. And this is true for all professions.

Now coming to the main part of your question. Abuse in any form should be unacceptable, even at the price of success. No one has the right to abuse anyone. Being a genius is less important than being a good human. As a society, we need to start rewarding only 'geniuses' who are good human beings.

I have been scolded by my supervisor (who is no genius) but with the sole intention of helping me. And that is not abuse, that is a gift because the truth was conveyed to me. I became confident, better. The supervisor would think for hours before giving his harsh opinion and would do it in a professional manner.

Then, I have also had a supervisor who was selfish to the core and would only look for his academic interest and exploit me, borderline abuse me. And that man is considered a gem in my university because of his tall accomplishments. After working with him for close to 2 years, I confronted him over a trivial matter. I decided to stand up. It just had to be done once, and his demeanor changed. I wish I had spoken up at least a year ago, I would have flourished more in my Ph.D.  as it was only after that moment that I could really enjoy my work.

So, one must determine if the strict demeanor of the supervisor is genuine or if it is totally selfish. And if it is abuse, then it is totally unacceptable. If they abuse for pleasure, it is the worst kind. If someone is accepting abuse in such a scenario, in the hope that it would make them a good researcher, it is akin to prostitution.

Also, note that there are examples of 'genius' students who never meet their supervisors during their Ph.D. study and won Nobel prizes. Science is above everything. And you as a person are more important than science.

Our society is changing. For example, more women are in the industry at least in Europe, the Americas, and most parts of Asia Pacific. Now mental health is important. We had a me-too movement. In a changing society, it is time that bullying, even by the "genius" is not accepted.

And, IMHO, movies are the last place to look for answers or form opinions.